# Moving Class to Next li, but Stuck on Same li

Tags: jquery

My goal here is to have a progress bar that instead of showing the next question number, it is a "next" button to scroll to the next question. Once you have clicked "next" the now active question number is active in the progress bar and the next li in the progress bar becomes the next button. 
My classes are changing as expected, however the second li in the progress bar stays as the next button instead of the third. So, it scrolls to the next question when you select Next, then #2 (over and over again).

I'm sure that I'm missing something simple, but I just can't get it to find the next element with the class "next" instead of staying stuck on the original "next".

Thank you!

Fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/eg6q44nm/

```
$('.next').click(function() {
      $('.next').removeClass('next').next().addClass('next');
      $('html,body').animate({ scrollTop:$('.question-container.active').next().offset().top}, 'slow');
      $('.progress-bar-steps.active').removeClass('active').addClass('answered');
      $('.question-container.active').removeClass('active').addClass('disabled').css('opacity', '.3').next().addClass('active').removeClass('disabled');
      $('.question-container').each(function (i, value){
        var qId = $(this).attr('id');
        if ($(this).hasClass('active')) {
            $(this).css('opacity','1.0');
            $('#progressBar').find("[data-item='" + qId + "']").addClass('active').text(i + 1);
            $('.progress-bar-steps.active').next('.progress-bar-steps').addClass('next').text('Next');
        } else {
          $(this).addClass('disabled');
        }
      });
    });
```

Comment: Registering the click handler only occurred once. You'll need to use a different selector to bind the click handler then check if that element has the `.next` class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Registering the click handler only occurred once. You'll need to use a different selector to bind the click handler then check if that element has the `.next` class.

```
$(".progress-bar-steps").on("click", function(e) {
    var button = $(this);
    if (button.hasClass("next")) {
        ...
    }
});
```

Comment: I ended up using this solution. I realized after the fact that the earlier solution triggered the scroll on all progress bar steps instead of just the one that had the class name of next. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is here:

```
var next = $('#progressBar').find('li.next')[ 0 ];
$(next).click(function() {
```

You're binding the click event to whatever `li` has the `next` class when the DOM loads.  You want it to be dynamic, so that any element with the class will be bound to the event.

You can do this :

```
$('li').on('click',next,function() {
```

This will "watch" for `li` elements that have the next class.

Here is your updated Fiddle:  https://jsfiddle.net/zephyr_hex/eg6q44nm/1/